# Conway's game of life - initialization

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say we've got a Grid with with 30 columns and 30 rows.

Rules for game of life in short:

- one cell has eight neighbor cells
- a cell gets alive as soon as a cell has three living neighbor cells
- a cell just survives if it has exactly two or three living neighbor cells

But how to initialize a grid with a determined size? Is there a rule how to exactly initialize some cells?

Comment: that's kinda the point of the game - different starting grid initializations produce different outcomes

Comment: please, what happens at borders?

Comment: The rules don't specify anything about borders. Most implementations have a rectangular border of empty cells which never generate life. It would certainly be possible for an implementation to allow the grid to grow as needed, creating a borderless "world", although of course the simulation may run out of memory at some point.

Comment: In the "Life" ecosystem, "Soup" is the world for the initial state. There are a few tools that help find interesting patterns: https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Soup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly it is initialized by the user (only user action required). Ofcourse you can also choose to initialize it yourself.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life):

> The "game" is a zero-player game, meaning that its evolution is determined by its initial state, requiring no further input. One interacts with the Game of Life by creating an initial configuration and observing how it evolves.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no rule. In fact, that's really the point, seeing what happens in later generation with any variety of starting configurations.

You could initialize each grid with ALIVE or EMPTY randomly. But usually the grid is initialized by user input, e.g. drawing at will on a screen which represents the first generation, and then starting the simulation so the screen will show later generations.

Comment: it's also common to read the input state from a file of some sort.

Comment: ...which could be considered a form of user input.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides inputing a random set of living cells, you can also create the initial state by selecting established "patterns". Patterns are recognized cell behaviors that occur each generation.

[Here's an example of a glider from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns)

[image: Here's an example of a glider]

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The poster asked two questions. The second is "Is there a rule how to exactly initialize some cells?" While there are no strict rules, most Life practitioners seem to be achieving specific patterns. Thus, they would start with configurations that would lend themselves to creating those patterns

Comment: The key word there is "rules". Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: The poster is looking for information on how to initialize a grid, just as I was when I came here. There are no "rules", so the answer that says that is correct. But visitors might find other answers useful. Someone who is looking for "rules" when there aren't any will probably find guidelines and other tools useful.

Comment: So say that in your answer. That would then answer the question.